# Add Attribute to Three.js Object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to maintain some information with shapes I'm creating. I use an HTML canvas for the texture, so I know I can keep the values in the element attributes arrays of the canvases. I'm wondering though, is there a more straight-forward way of maintaining attributes that works for all Three.js shapes regardless of how they are constructed?

Comment: It would help to know why this was down-voted.

Comment: I don't know why the question has been downvoted. But, to me, your question is confusing. Are you talking about instances of the three.js [Shape class](https://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Core/Shape)? If so, why not just add the needed property to the instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear as to the correct answer, prisoner849 provided it in the comment he made to another response: use the THREE.Mesh.userData property.

Answer (score 3):

The advantage (or the problem) with Javascript, is that you can do almost everything with your objects. You can add, or even delete attributes as much as you want any time.

Thus, you can add every property you want to THREE objects by simply giving it a value :

```
 myThreeObject.myProperty = myValue ;
```

Be careful though, if you haven't assigned a value to the property, this property does not exist (yet), thus, don't forget to check if the value exist before reading it :

```
if( "undefined" !== typeof myThreeObject.myProperty )
    // ...
```

Comment: `THREE.Mesh()`, for example, has the `userData` property, intended exactly to store the user's data there.

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks prisoner849.